# Module dependency and relations

Tags: php, yii, architecture, module

> "Some commonly used features, such as user management, comment management, may be developed in terms of modules so that they can be reused easily in future projects." - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module

I have a lot of projects that requires a user. Every time quite the same database structure and features. Registration, login, logout etc.
Yii tells me that i can reuse modules. Cool... let's start:

I have 3 parts: User, Campaign and Website.

In this project the CampaignModule has a relation to the UserModule (campaign_user [user_id, campaign_id])

The WebsiteModule has a relation to the CampaignModule and to the UserModule.

I want to reuse the UserModule in other projects with features like registration, login, edit etc.

Actual situation:
After creating models with gii every one has relations and dependencies across the modules.
e.g.

```
UserModule: 'campaigns' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Campaign', 'user_id'),
```

To use the WebsiteModule it's necessary to include the User- and CampaignModule.
Now i even have to include Website- and CampaignModule to use the UserModule!

I also want to update the UserModule across many projects and maybe build a framework with some basic modules.

What is the right way to plan an architecture like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [yii-user module](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user), what they do, is they allow you to specify additional relations for the User model, on the module configuration:

```
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    $relations = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->relations;
    if (!isset($relations['profile']))
        $relations['profile'] = array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Profile', 'user_id');
    return $relations;
}
```

So you can do something like:

```
'modules'=>array(
    'user' => array(
            ...
            'relations' => array(
              'categories' => array(CActiveRecord::HAS_MANY, 'Category', "user_id"),
              'account' => array(CActiveRecord::HAS_ONE, 'Account', "user_id"),
            ),
            ...
        ),
  ),
```

Comment: This is a good solution for the relations. But i still have a problem to find a global solution for the modules. If the WebsiteModule has a WebsiteRatingModel i don't want to use WebsiteRating::model()-> ... in my application or other modules. I want to communicate with the models through an interface or kind of api. Writing Yii::app()->getModule('website')->website->getWebsiteRating(123) is not the best idea... (->website is a componet set in module init())